# WIndows-10 Mobile: "The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, c++-cx

I have a C# app targeting UWP/Windows-10 for desktop & mobile platforms. The C# app calls into native component written in C++. My native C++ code has Visual C++ component extensions(C++/CX). The native code is then packaged as a .dll & bundled along with the app.

The app works perfectly fine on Desktop, i.e when I run it in **x86** or **x64**, **Local Machine** , but encounters this error while running on Mobile,  i.e. on **x86 Mobile Emulator** or on an **ARM device(Nokia 950)**

> **The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)":null**

Basically, I am not able to load my native libraries in **Mobile** mode. 

 I have already read this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx). My native C++ code is not using any unsupported api's.

I tried both **/"DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP"** and **/D"WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP"**, but it didnt help.

 Is there a different set of toolchain which I need to use while building native .dll for mobile? My desktop & mobile native .dll's use the same linker settings/flags. 

 Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be Microsoft issue. I have contacts with some Microsoft Program Manager's. I provided them a sample project which exhibits this behavior.

 They analyzed the sample project & said that this indeed was an issue on Microsoft's end.

The issue here is that when the app is deployed in Desktop mode (x86 or x64 Local Machine) "**ucrt is already available on the platform**" & hence the app works fine.

On Mobile platform ***ucrt*** is not available & will be pushed only when it is referenced in the project. But due some bug on Microsoft's platform this doesnt seem to happen & I was not able to run the app on Mobile device/emulator.

Comment: Could you provide some more information as to how you resolved this? Or even if it is resolvable? I'm experiencing the same issue and am not seeing a way to reference Universal CRT for mobile. Thanks

Comment: Hi @CharlesR.PortwoodII, As of today this issue cannot be resolved. MS mobile framework has to reference & load Universal CRT for mobile devices/emulator. The current framework is unable to load ucrt & as such we need to wait for MS to fix this issue in their framework.

Comment: `The specified module could not be found.` error in my case indicated that an included file couldn't be reference on mobile (in my case it was <wincrypt.h>). Windows 10 mobile does have access to ucrt in 10.0.10240+.