# 0x8007007E only in Windows Phone target

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm targeting a C# application with a UWP C++ Universal Windows Project reference that is in the very same solution. This application works properly without any error in Windows Desktop, but when I try to run it on a Windows Phone device I'm getting the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. >(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at *CALLED METHOD HERE*
   at Demo.MainPage..ctor()'Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded
```

I've checked the *csproj* to see if it was referencing directly a *wincmd* file or the *dll* but it really is referencing the other project.

I've tried to check the device storage but I couldn't find a way to explore the deployed app contents in the device.

Target Platform version/min.version: 10.0.14393.0

EDIT 1:

Looks like the issue is that the DLL produced is referencing ucrtbased.dll

```
File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
    vccorlib140d_app.DLL
    MSVCP140D_APP.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
    api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-winrt-error-l1-1-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll
    api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
    api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll
    api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-2.dll
```

EDIT 2:

Visual Studio is including ucrt/arm path as Library Path. I'm using Visual Studio 2017

```
LibraryPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\lib\ARM\store;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\ARM;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\lib\ARM;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\arm;;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\arm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.2\lib\um\arm;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\arm
```

EDIT 3:

For some reason, it seems that _ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE=1 is being inherited from somewhere allowing ARM targets (all projects) to access desktop APIs. Could this be causing an issue?

EDIT 4:
With dumpbin /imports I cna get a list of ucrtbased.dll functions that my program is using, most of them stdlib functions:

```
ucrtbased.dll
          10D0E7E4 Import Address Table
          10D0F430 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

              527 strcpy_s
              523 strcat_s
               69 __stdio_common_vsprintf_s
              3B2 _wsplitpath_s
              55F wcscpy_s
              396 _wmakepath_s
              174 _initterm_e
              33C _wassert
              175 _invalid_parameter
                5 _CrtDbgReportW
              562 wcslen
              52C strlen
              47F free
              4DC mbstowcs_s
              526 strcpy
              53A strtol
               CD _difftime64
              296 _mktime64
               6A __stdio_common_vsscanf
              575 wcstombs
              500 realloc
              3C2 _wtoi
              54F toupper
               36 __acrt_iob_func
              173 _initterm
              4FE rand
              410 ceil
              44A exit
              166 _gmtime64_s
              318 _time64
              4D3 malloc
               E0 _errno
              3D0 abort
              52F strncmp
              12C _ftime64
              55C wcscmp
              11D _free_dbg
              203 _malloc_dbg
                4 _CrtDbgReport
               A2 _callnewh
              2BD _seh_filter_dll
               B7 _configure_narrow_argv
              170 _initialize_narrow_environment
              171 _initialize_onexit_table
              2B1 _register_onexit_function
               E6 _execute_onexit_table
               C3 _crt_atexit
               C2 _crt_at_quick_exit
               A5 _cexit
               5D __stdio_common_vfprintf
```

Current suspicion: use of ADVAPI32.dll dependent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WIndows-10 Mobile: "The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658721/windows-10-mobile-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hre)

Comment: So you are saying that this is a possible duplicate of a unsolved unexplained answer? There are two people in there commenting two distinct problems and the author selected his reply as the answer, however it does not explain how to resolve this issue claiming to be a bug in the Microsoft counterpart. I am using very recent builds in the target devices 10.0.14393.0. If this is a bug could you please explain how can I avoid it and how can ensure that my application won't include ucrt references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the culprit in my stack: ADVAPI32.dll.

I was using a dependency that was loading SystemFunction036 (RtlGenRandom), the solution was to rework the code to work with an equivalent UWP function that does the same.

Microsoft should really rethink the way they report this kind of issue to developers since the exception seems completely unrelated to the issue. A simple exception telling that ADVAPI32.dll is the culprit that is loading functions that are not allowed in the mobile variant of UWP. Since this is a runtime issue your code would compile fine without you never know that your code won't work, except if you test it.